# View and save email as PDF

Tags: mu4e

I want to save an email receipt as a PDF. I type `a` and `v` (for Action and View as PDF) and get `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`. How can I save a message as a PDF file?

Comment: You might need to put msg2pdf working in order to achieve that. Alternatively, you can open the message in your web browser and save it from there as a pdf file.

Comment: When I launch help for `mu4e-msg2pdf`, I get: `is a variable defined in ‘mu4e-actions.el’. Its value is nil`. I installed `mu` with `brew install mu --with-emacs` and running `brew upgrade --with-emacs mu` gives `Error: invalid option: --with-emacs`. How do I reinstall `mu` with `mu4e` or `msg2pdf`? Or how do I get the file location of the current message on disk?

Comment: As you can see from this reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/93scvw/mu4e_and_msg2pdf_on_arch/]) msg2pdf is not the easiest/most reliable way of getting a pdf. I'd use the web browser shortcut instead.

Comment: I found how to view a message in the browser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258133/how-to-view-mu4e-emacs-buffer-in-browser), adding to my configuration `(add-to-list 'mu4e-view-actions '("ViewInBrowser" . mu4e-action-view-in-browser) t)`. Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) installed, here's a function that saves the PDF to your Desktop automatically:

```el
(defun mu4e-action-save-to-pdf (msg)
  (let* ((date (mu4e-message-field msg :date))
         (infile (mu4e~write-body-to-html msg))
         (outfile (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d%H%M%S.pdf" date)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (shell-command
       (format "wkhtmltopdf %s ~/Desktop/%s" infile outfile) t))))

(add-to-list 'mu4e-view-actions '("Save to PDF" . mu4e-action-save-to-pdf) t)
```

Comment: @mmorin I replaced the `call-process-shell-command` function with `shell-command`. Can you try again. You could also replace it with `print` to examine the output.

Comment: I asked [this follow-up question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55771/how-to-include-headers-when-exporting-a-message-as-pdf) about including message headers in the PDF.

Comment: I see the From, To, Date, and Subject header fields in the PDF. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I included a picture of the PDF output from your code in that other thread. I have `mu4e-mu-version 1.2.0`, how about you? The function `mu4e~write-body-to-html` does not mention if headers are included. Does the body of a mu4e message include the headers?

Comment: Try the `mu4e~write-body-to-html` function in the master branch and see if that works for you. I'm using mu version 1.3.4 C.

Answer (score 1):

To get the same result, but with an additional step, I suggest to view the email in your web browser with `(add-to-list 'mu4e-view-actions '("ViewInBrowser" . mu4e-action-view-in-browser) t)` and to then print it to a pdf file.