# How to include headers when exporting a message as PDF?

Tags: mu4e, pdf

As a follow-up to [this question about exporting as PDF](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51180/view-and-save-email-as-pdf/51282?noredirect=1#comment79180_51282), I want to export a message as a PDF. One answer in that thread views the message in a browser window and I can then save as a PDF from the browser:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'mu4e-view-actions '("ViewInBrowser" . mu4e-action-view-in-browser) t)
```

The other is similar but does the work behind the scenes with [WebKit HTML to PDF](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). Here is one example of the output of the latter command:

[image: PDF output of a message, without headers]

Both miss the header fields, such as sender, date, and subject, and the message starts immediately at the body.

How can I include message headers when exporting to PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in version 1.3. You can try the `mu4e~write-body-to-html` function in the master branch.

Comment: Yes, just loading the latest `mu4e-actions.el` works. I didn't want to have a separate installation of `1.3.x` lest I damage the current one. I'll wait until `1.3` is in release.