# mu4e how to convert msg to pdf?

Tags: mu4e, pdf

I try to convert to pdf with this following code [found on Emacs SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51180/view-and-save-email-as-pdf):

```el
(defun mu4e-action-save-to-pdf (msg)
   (let* ((date (mu4e-message-field msg :date))
          (infile (mu4e~write-body-to-html msg))
          (outfile (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d%H%M%S.pdf" date)))
     (with-temp-buffer
       (shell-command
         (format "wkhtmltopdf %s ~/Desktop/%s" infile outfile) t))))

(add-to-list 'mu4e-view-actions '("Save to PDF" . mu4e-action-save-to-pdf) t)
```

But when  I launch the action it says:

> void function mu4e-write-body-to-html

When I `M-x mu4e-write<TAB>` nothing exists.
Can someone tell me how to fix that?

Comment: I edited your question but for future reference, you should have provided a link to where you found that code.

Comment: The function `mu4e~write-body-to-html` is defined in `mu4e-view-old.el[c]` and seems to be outdated. Note the tilde `~` in the name, which is a non-standard convention for names in Emacs. You can try `M-x load-library RET mu4e-view-old` to load the library (assuming it's in your `load-path`): that should resolve the error message you get, but whether that will actually work... I don't know but I somehow doubt it.

Comment: @jagrg can you take a look at this? You answered the linked question, so I figure you know more about `mu4e` than I do (which is not hard, since I know almost nothing about it). [I'm not sure whether the at-reference will work btw, but I thought it's worth trying]

Comment: And how can I find this library or at least the lisp code for that function ?

Comment: It should be in the same place as `mu4e.el`  I think. Did `M-x load-library RET mu4e-view-old` not work?

Comment: No I also did I find in Finder but not such file found..  Only have in /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa/mu4e-1.8.7 mu4e-view.el ..

Comment: No I also did I find in Finder but not such file found..  Only have in /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa/mu4e-1.8.7 mu4e-view.el ..  I was thinking in the  wrong way at first instance.. I believed that this function could convert any mail to pdt but I think that the mail must be formatted with html tags/attributes..  I found this and tried and get "No body part found" when opening a mail and running the function.  I found this at https://groups.google.com/g/mu-discuss/c/dSsEbZ1SHLI?pli=1.

Comment: My other question could be at least how to convert any mail to html mail (I know I can open it to a web browser then print to pdf) but would be nice to do all that stuff within Emacs..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140192/discussion-between-mcp-and-nickd).

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, `mu4e` no longer uses its own built-in view mode, it relies on functions from Gnus. If that's correct, I suspect the file mu4e-view-old.el is no longer loaded automatically. You can load it via `(require 'mu4e-view-old)`. That should make the function you want available.